Character fail to load differently everytime the scene is reloaded
Every time my character dies, the scene is full reloaded with reload_current_scene(). but anytime it is reloaded the player is loaded differently:
-1st time it works perfectly
-2nd time some animations are missing
-3rd time some sprites change their position
-4th time the main scene closes few seconds after being loaded.
Video showing the "issue": https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hVHOhppU2c4_BgBGz14poDamjhtL790/view?usp=sharing
I'm new to godot and I don't know where to start to look for a solution. Any guiadance  will be appreciated.
I don't know where to start to look for a solution, there ios no error in the debugger.
I change the way animations where played and now i'm using AnimationTree, but it didn't solve the problem.

there is a tab on the bottom of the godot editor, which shows warnings and errors. With each restart the error count is rising in your video. Check out this tab and look, if the errors help you understand the problem. If not add them to your question

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thanks to for the orientation Mr Bugfish! I investigate the issue and it seems to be a bug. The error was the one descrived here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/73168 And the workaround I use was the one commented by seffa1.
Basicaly there is a problem reloading the Skeleton modifier stack after get_tree().reload_current_scene(). So the workaround for this is save the modifier stack resource, and reload it in the _ready(). I used this code:
onready var modification_stack = preload("res://Player/player_skeleton_modification_stack.tres")
func _ready():
    %Skeleton.set_modification_stack(modification_stack.duplicate())
    %Skeleton.get_modification_stack().enabled = true

That's a simple workaround for the problem. Hope it'll be useful!
